# How to get a list of controls in a groupbox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, groupbox

In standard WinForms development I would do the following:

```
foreach (Control in groupBox1.Controls)
{
     MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
}
```

How does a guy do this in WPF?  I have a Grid inside the GroupBox and a number of controls in the grid (buttons etc.) but can't seem to figure out how to get each control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As MSDN advises, you will need to iterate the controls as children of the `GroupBox`. Also, note that you usually need to add a `Grid` into your `GroupBox` to be able to add new controls into that `GroupBox`. So you will need to get the children of the `Grid` in that `GroupBox` and iterate through them, something like this:

```
//iterate through the child controls of "grid"
int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
              Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid, i);
                if (childVisual is TextBox)
                {
                    //write some logic code
                }
               else
               {

               }
            }
```

You might find this useful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/93ebca8f-2977-4c36-b437-9c82a22266f6

Answer (score 1):

Simpler code would be something like

```
foreach (Control control in Grid.Children)
 {
  //Code here for what you want to do.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread and that the answer marked as accepted works, but it could be simpler (and simple is better).
Anthony got the idea but failed to mention that one needs to iterate on the grid inside the GroupBox and failed to explain how to get there.

In XAML give a name to the main grid inside the GroupBox control (here assuming you named it "GroupBoxGridName"). This will allow you to search for controls inside this Grid including the controls inside any grid in the main group box grid (recursive).

Then do this in the C# code:

```
foreach (ControlType myControl in GroupBoxGridName.ChildrenOfType<ControlType>)
{
        MessageBox.Show(MyControl.Name);
}
```

Where ControlType can be general as Control or a defined type like TextBox or ComboBox or whatever.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `.Controls`, you'll be looking for the `.Children` property.

Additionally, that will only return first order children.  You'll want to recursively find all children of all controls if you truly want all descendants of the `GroupBox`.

Comment: -1 this answer is wrong. GroupBox doesn't contain Children property.