# Cannot get Controls from GroupBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get the IsChecked value from all Checkboxes in a groupbox. I keep searching around and everyone seems to point to yourControl.Controls.OfType().... The problem is, I cannot get controls off of my groupbox. I get "GroupBox does not contain a definition for Controls" error whenever I try to code it.

I am very new to this, so sorry if this has been answered somewhere else that I've looked and it just wasn't clicking for me. I am creating a WPF C# app in Visual Studio 2017.

I have included part of my xaml

```
<GroupBox Name="Computers" Header="Computers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Height="315" Margin="21,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216">
<CheckBox Name="Training01CB" Content="Training01" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Height="15" Width="78" IsChecked="False"/>
<CheckBox Name="Training02CB" Content="Training02" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Height="15" Width="78" IsChecked="False"/>
</GroupBox>
```

I'd like to do something like this:
foreach(Computers.Controls.OfType().Checked)
{
   run private code here
}

Comment: For iterate controls inside the GroupBox you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505400/how-to-get-a-list-of-controls-in-a-groupbox-in-wpf)

Comment: Your XAML is invalid and won't compile. You can only set the Content of the GroupBox to a single object.

Comment: Avoid trying write Winforms code in a WPF app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XAML you have posted is invalid and won't compile. You can only set the `Content` of the `GroupBox` to a single object.

However, if you set it to a `Panel` and add the `CheckBox` elements to this `Panel`, you could iterate through its `Children` property like this:

```
Panel panel = Computers.Content as Panel;
if (panel != null)
{
    foreach (CheckBox checkBox in panel.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<GroupBox Name="Computers" Header="Computers">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="Training01CB" Content="Training01" IsChecked="False"/>
        <CheckBox Name="Training02CB" Content="Training02" IsChecked="False"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been trying to read and figure things out on my own but I was banging my head against the wall. You saved me! Thank you so much!